# Flutter: Unable to load text assets

Tags: dart, flutter

My file `endpoints.json` is in `/WORKPLACE_DIR/assets/json/endpoints.json`

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

I have updated my `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
    - assets/json/endpoints.json
```

In `/tests/some_test.dart`

I do

```
test('my test', () async {
      final endpoints = json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/endpoints.json"));
    }
```

It still gives an error

```
ERROR: Unable to load asset: assets/json/endpoints.json
package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 221:7  PlatformAssetBundle.load
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                            _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart        PlatformAssetBundle.load
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                            _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart        PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 67:33  AssetBundle.loadString
```

I have tried `flutter clean` but it still gives this error. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Isn't the extension `.txt` incorrect in your `json.decode` call ?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong logs. Corrected. It should be json

Comment: Can you confirm your assets folder is in the root of the app directory? Are you able to access other assets in the folder e.g an image?

Comment: Same issue here, don't know how to fix.

Comment: I still have no fix. I just used a `constants.dart` and assigned a constant to the JSON. Thankfully JSON and dart HashMaps have the same syntax.

Comment: Try to add `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before running tests

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem with images. The reason was simple, I skipped the tab before "assets:". If the words "flutter:" and "assets:" are on the same level in your pubspec.yaml file you will get the "unable to load asset" error. So just add the tab before "assets:" and "- assets/json/endpoints.json".

Answer (score 6):

Hello perhaps adding the assets to **pubspec.yaml** will help to solve the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're in submodule, you need to put
`packages/your_submodule_name/` in front of the assets path

For example :

```
await rootBundle.loadString("packages/my_module/assets/json/endpoints.json");
```